# Is there a way for me to make a screen similar to the ICS voice typing screen with the flashing red glow in my Android app?

Tags: android, voice

I'm making a voice transcriptionist software and it would be nice if I could copy the UI and UI style that shows up when you use your voice to type on Android?

Here's how it looks if you don't know what I mean: [pic of it here](http://gottabemobile.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/ICS-Screen15.jpg)

What are my options in doing so? Does Google provide any kind of API or is there a way that I could steal this nice looking screen for my app? The point is that I don't want to use Google's voice search... I want to record the audio and send it off for humans to transcribe, but I like the UI a lot and would like to use a similar UI in my app.